# Bond-order parameter $g_6(r)$

Tags: bond, colloids

I would like to know the explicit steps to compute the bond correlation function
$$g_6(r) = \langle\Psi_6^*(0) \cdot \Psi_6(r)\rangle$$
for colloids in my experiment (2D). I have the position of all my particles, I know how to compute the individual hexagonal order parameter for particle $k$
$$ \Psi_{6,k} = \sum_{j=1}^N\frac{\exp[6i\theta_{kj}]}{n_j}$$
where $n_j$ is the number of neighbors of the particle $k$ (usually computed via Voronoi Tessellation that define the neighbor without cutoff) and $\theta_{kj}$ is the angle between $\vec{r}=\vec{r}_j-\vec{r}_k$ (the bond) and an arbitrary axis (x-axis for example)

But I cannot see how $\Psi_{6,k}$ depends on the position to apply the formula for $g_6(r)$. How can I compute $\Psi_{6k}(r)$? Is it some kind of average or density function?

Comment: Please define $\theta_{kj}$ and $n_j$, and what is the subscript $k$ as well?

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/461153/bond-order-correlation-function may be of use

Comment: Rushing out but looking at the link of the physics forum it seems (in the Questions language) k is the index of a particle, and thus you get position dependence via that index

Comment: @IanBush I have updated the question. If $\psi_{6k}(r)$  is the order parameter for the particle $k$, I know the value of $\psi_{6k}(r_k)$ but not the value for all $r$. Then, how can I compute $\psi_{6k}(r)$?

Comment: See [this](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/347295494_Phase_behavior_of_Lennard-Jones_particles_in_two_dimensions) which might help (or references therein). Looks to me like they compute the value by summing over angles ($\theta$).

Comment: If I have understand properly from all the references that I have read, let said that I choose particle $ i $ as reference, then $\vec{r}_i = \vec{0}$ and $| \vec{r}_j | = r$. I have to compute the probability distribution function for $ \Psi_i(r) $. Then in 2D the value $ \Psi_j $ at distance $ r $ on a shell of radius $ r $ and $ r + dr $ should be $ d \Psi (r) = 2 \pi \, r \, \rho_\psi (r) \, dr $, and the correlation have to be compute as $g_{6} (r) = <\rho_\psi(0) \cdot \rho_\psi(r)>$, where <> means ensemble average ... Isn 't it? It's a bit confused to me ..

Comment: @user239504 Yes, that looks correct.

Comment: @IanBush I have try to compute it in this way, but I cannot find the same results that another old program that I want to replace with this new program that I'm writing (that's why I want to understand every step). Could you please explain more explicitly the process that I have to follow? I have try to do something similar to this link for $g(r)$ but with $g_6(r)$, but I'm not able to do it properly [http://www.physics.emory.edu/faculty/weeks//idl/gofr2.html]

Comment: OK, that's not totally informative is it. Few things to do today but will try to find time to write an answer later.

Comment: I would say it would be more fitting to have your code as another answer rather than as an edit to the question.

Comment: I have removed the code from the question. Please add it as an answer instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assume we are given a configuration of atoms $\{{\bf r_i}\}$ and any other data required to characterise the atomic layout, e.g. any lattice vectors if we have periodic boundary conditions in any of the 3 possible directions. With each of the atoms let us associate a property that can be characterised by a scalar quantity  $\{p_i\}$. For example $p_i=1 \space \forall i$ is one possibility, this will lead to something closely related to the radial distribution function. Another possibility is $p_i=q_i$ where $q_i$ is the charge on atom $i$. Another possibility is $\Psi_{6,k}$ as defined in the question. It doesn't really matter what, as long as you can calculate a scalar quantity associated with each of the atoms of interest the recipe below will work <sup>[1]</sup>

So the first step in the process is for the given configuration calculate $\{p_i\}$ for the property of interest. Now we want to calculate the average of $p_i^\dagger . p_j$ where atom $i$ and atom $j$ are separated by a given distance $d$. In practice on a computer we divide the distance range into a number of different bins, each of which cover the range $d$ to $d + \delta d$. So the method will be something like the following - **but note I have had to make assumptions about how you wish to normalise the accumulated values**; you may have to modify that according to what the relevant literature says. Anyway the essence of the method

1. Set to zero two sets of bins, one to accumulate the correlation terms to, one to count how many atom pairs are in each distance range
2. Loop over all the first particles $i$
3. Loop over all the second particles $j$<sup>[2]</sup>
4. Calculate $v=p_i^\dagger . p_j$
5. Calculate the distance between atom $i$ and atom $j$
6. Work out which bin that distance corresponds to
7. Add $v$ to the appropriate correlation accumulator bin
8. Increment the appropriate atom pair counter bin
9. Finish the loop over $j$
10. Finish the loop over $i$
11. The average correlation at each distance is the value of the correlation accumulator bin divided by the atom pair counter bin corresponding to the distance of interest

This generates the contribution for a single configuration - the final step is if appropriate to average over a large number of configurations.

---

<sup>[1]</sup> For the more mathematically minded I would normally convolute $\{p_i\}$ with delta functions at the atoms positions to represent the distribution of the property of interest. This complication is not needed here, but makes the argument more easily generalised to non-point particles

<sup>[2]</sup> Looping over all atoms in the $j$ loop is not the most efficient way to do this, and will be *very* slow for large systems. If you care about time to solution you should set up a neighbour list for each atom before the loop, and then in the $j$ loop only go over those atoms within the maximum distance of interest from the reference atom $i$. this reduces the scaling of the algorithm from $O(N^2)$ to $O(N)$ where $N$ is the number of atoms in the system

Comment: I see! Thank you very much for the explanation, now it is more clear for me. Respect to the normalization I think that I just need to divide for the total number of particles to find the correct function. I'm gonna add at the end of my question the code (write in python) that I'm doing for people that maybe need it in the future!

Comment: I almost wrote some code, but as a Fortran or C guy I didn't want to frighten people ...

Comment: It looks like $p_i$ and $p_j$ become vectors, rather than scalars in step 4.

Comment: A dot can be used to mean multiply, it's not just for dot products. I'll remove if it causes confusion

Comment: It's fine for me, a presume that $v=...$ is just the expression for the value in brackets, it could be for scalars $v=\Psi(\vec{r}_i) \, \Psi(\vec{r}_j)$, vectors  $v=\vec{a}(t_1) \cdot \vec{a}(t_2)$, etc

Comment: @IanBush - Fortran-77 and C guy here, don't hold back!

Comment: Fortran 2003 nowadays - nothing earlier is worth using. Too late in the UK now, maybe tomorrow